# What could have caused this scale-like pattern on the surface of this LCD Monitor?

Tags: display, lcd

Today I was out refurbishing computer monitors like usual, when I came across this:

[image: weird monitor image]

Note the scale-like pattern. Over the years, I've seen and refurbished thousands of monitors - hundreds of this model and size alone - and this is the first time I've seen something like this happen. Some information from direct observation and tinkering:

- The 'scales' can be felt by brushing the monitor. The texture is tactile, not just visual.

  - Thus, the texture seems to be on the surface (the clear plastic top layer of the screen), not on the LCD beneath.
  - I think the texture goes outwards from the screen, rather than inwards, though it was hard to tell by scratching at it.
- I can't scratch off the texture, and spraying the screen with Windex and wiping it off doesn't do anything special.
- The pattern seems to taper off towards the edges, and covers almost the entire screen (with the exception of the bottom-left corner)
- The monitor works perfectly - powers on normally, displays the image just as expected (standard AC power input, VGA image input).  This pretty much rules out electrical damage as a possible cause.

I pulled in everyone else who knew anything about computer hardware who was in the warehouse at the time, and we all came up with no ideas as to what could have caused this. I'm burning with curiosity - does anyone else know?

Comment: Looks like maybe, heat and moisture has gotten into the LCD itself, and worked it's way outwards.

Comment: Or someone used a cleaning agent that was harmful to the covering